# CUPS Print Delays

Tags: printing, java

I am a developer of an open source Java printing plugin for the web browser and we have a client that reports 250ms delay in printing on Ubuntu, but no other OS.  He has tested printing on Windows and OSX without issues.

In our test lab we are able to reproduce this delay.  Although minor, this affects the capabilities of an Ubuntu kiosk he is developing.

We would like to obtain paid support for this issue to quickly address it (rather than spend time searching) however the Canonical support form tells us our deployment size is too small for a support plan and instead directs me to this page. :)

Has anyone else experienced such an issue?  I cannot imagine this a very common concern among Desktop users since this specific need for real-time printing is only going to affect industry application (i.e. time critical production use), but I'm certain we aren't the first to try this, nor report this.  Google has offered some suggestions but we've tried every sensible one to no avail.

Our printer uses a Generic/Text driver, hardware is a brand new Epson TM88V and we are using Java to issue the commands to the printer.

The source code for our software is located here:
http://www.qzindustries.com/download (LGPL 2.1)

The tutorial we give our customers is located here:
http://www.qzindustries.com/TutorialRawUbuntu

Any advice on this matter is well appreciated.

**Edit:**  This bug report may be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1001028

-Tres Finocchiaro

Comment: Have other browsers been tried? - web interfaces are not always the fastest... Also, it might be relevant, but is this openJDK java or Oracle JDK? - vague thing on differences [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360011/technically-what-is-the-main-difference-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk). You should be able to use `sudo update-java-alternatives -l` to find that. This however may be more of an issue with the drivers.

Comment: We are comparing Firefox to Firefox, Chrome to Chrome.  Yes others have been tried.  They always print immediately on OS X and Windows.   We have bench-marked both Oracle JRE 7.x and OpenJDK JRE 7.x (not JDK).  Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Did it got fixed?

Comment: @Briam, our client upgraded to 14.04 for now, which has fixed this.  We haven't had time to raise this issue with Canonical, but all signs point to a bug with the operating system/cups and we plan to follow-up.  We rarely recommend bleeding edge changes (such as a changing to a recently released OS) to fix a problem, so its still on our radar to get fixed.  Our support contract with Canonical clearly covers bugs like this, its just a matter of placing the lengthy support call.  Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use real time kernel.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
```

For MIDI this kernel reduced delay from ~0,5s to inaudible delay below 0,05s. I also have client with same configuration (not same model) JAVA / RAW label printer, if you need, I can do some testing for you.

Comment: that is fantastic news.I will take you up on that offer.  I will send you a link to the licensed version of the software to try (free version would suffice however the licensed version has the necessary certificates to run without the security prompts).  No installation is needed as it is a web page.  Please email me tres@qzindustries.com.  I will have my brother test with lowlatency kernel too.

Comment: Email sent, check inbox.

Comment: Replied, thank you.  It would be very nice to have some paid Canonical support on his issue... Is anyone aware of a 3rd party that offers technical support for items like this on Ubuntu?  I'm afraid this may be a bug with USB connected Raw Devices: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1001028

Comment: Due to the very specific nature of this issue, we are purchasing a support plan via: http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=667  We are a development shop with 2 computers, so we are purchasing the minimum 5-computer tier and escalating the issue with Ubuntu technical support.  I will update this thread with the answer once it is discovered.